# hg undo overwrite

Tags: mercurial, undo

Accidentally used `>` instead of `>>` !

The overwritten file was added by `hg add` two days ago but was never commited.

Can `hg` undo that for me (maybe by magic) ?

Comment: If it was added with `hg add` then that implies it wasn't tracked, so Mercurial would have no knowledge of the file or its various revisions in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you're using Eclipse, you can look into the "local history".

If you use Mac, Timemachine might have saved the file.

If you're using openSUSE with btrfs, the zypper snapshot mechanism might have kept a copy.